# Sequence privileges for a specific user and schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sequence-sql

Is there any query that can get all the sequences in a schema that is granted to a particular user in postgresql?

I only could get the solution for listing all the sequences and not specific to any user or schema.
Would appreciate if anyone could provide a script for it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.